# Reload only one symbol in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

I'm using the following command in WinDBG to reload all symbols

```
!sym noisy
.sympath srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
.reload /f
!sym quiet
```

How can I reload the symbol of only one DLL? e.g ntdll

Comment: .reload /f ntdll.dll optionally with base and size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i Commented use the module name along with base and size optionally see below

only ntdll is loaded by default on start at system Breakpoint

```
0:000> lm
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`ae300000 00007ff6`ae32e000   cdb        (deferred)
00007fff`142f0000 00007fff`14a22000   dbgeng     (deferred)
00007fff`210c0000 00007fff`212b3000   dbghelp    (deferred)
00007fff`36050000 00007fff`360f9000   dbgmodel   (deferred)
00007fff`45040000 00007fff`45075000   XmlLite    (deferred)
00007fff`533d0000 00007fff`5346e000   msvcp_win   (deferred)
00007fff`53470000 00007fff`53496000   bcrypt     (deferred)
00007fff`53600000 00007fff`536fa000   ucrtbase   (deferred)
00007fff`53700000 00007fff`539a5000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)
00007fff`54360000 00007fff`543e1000   bcryptPrimitives   (deferred)
00007fff`54450000 00007fff`544ee000   msvcrt     (deferred)
00007fff`54570000 00007fff`548a6000   combase    (deferred)
00007fff`54d80000 00007fff`54e9f000   RPCRT4     (deferred)
00007fff`55e70000 00007fff`55f22000   KERNEL32   (deferred)
00007fff`56170000 00007fff`56235000   OLEAUT32   (deferred)
00007fff`56340000 00007fff`56530000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          f:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\27341C1B9147DD100EC194BFDD47B97A1\ntdll.pdb
```

loading symbol for a single module viz dbgmodel.dll

```
0:000> .reload /f dbgmodel.dll
0:000> lm
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`ae300000 00007ff6`ae32e000   cdb        (deferred)
00007fff`142f0000 00007fff`14a22000   dbgeng     (deferred)
00007fff`210c0000 00007fff`212b3000   dbghelp    (deferred)
00007fff`36050000 00007fff`360f9000   dbgmodel   (pdb symbols)          f:\symbols\dbgmodel.pdb\9A0AE73EBC9949A30EF879B505AF2C761\dbgmodel.pdb
00007fff`45040000 00007fff`45075000   XmlLite    (deferred)
00007fff`533d0000 00007fff`5346e000   msvcp_win   (deferred)
00007fff`53470000 00007fff`53496000   bcrypt     (deferred)
00007fff`53600000 00007fff`536fa000   ucrtbase   (deferred)
00007fff`53700000 00007fff`539a5000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)
00007fff`54360000 00007fff`543e1000   bcryptPrimitives   (deferred)
00007fff`54450000 00007fff`544ee000   msvcrt     (deferred)
00007fff`54570000 00007fff`548a6000   combase    (deferred)
00007fff`54d80000 00007fff`54e9f000   RPCRT4     (deferred)
00007fff`55e70000 00007fff`55f22000   KERNEL32   (deferred)
00007fff`56170000 00007fff`56235000   OLEAUT32   (deferred)
00007fff`56340000 00007fff`56530000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          f:\symbols\ntdll.pdb\27341C1B9147DD100EC194BFDD47B97A1\ntdll.pdb
0:000>
```